# SQL error - near " at line 1

Tags: php, mysql

I have combed this code and cannot for the life of me find the error.  This is a PHP file I'm going to run as a cron job to check for ended auctions, and to send out an email to the auction owner at the end of the auction.  The code is sending an email to the auction lister, but it is only looping through 1 auction.  I'm assuming it's because it's finding an error in the code and dying but I cannot find the error.

Here is the entirety of the code...

```
    // Include the configuration file
require_once 'includes/config.php';

$currenttime = strtotime('now');

//Query the dateabase for listings which have ended in the past 5 minutes.
$endauctionquery = "SELECT * FROM listings WHERE end_date < NOW() AND cron_ended=0";
        $endauction = mysql_query($endauctionquery) or die('SQL Error :: '.mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($endauction) > 0){

        //Loop through the listings and send the appropriate emails
        while($endauctionrow=mysql_fetch_assoc($endauction)) {

        //Global variables for the loop
        $sellerid = $endauctionrow['user_id'];
        $itemquantity = $endauctionrow['item_quant'];
        $listingid = $endauctionrow['id'];
        $sellerquery = "SELECT * FROM settings WHERE user_id=$sellerid";
        $sellersql = mysql_query($sellerquery) or die('SQL Error :: '.mysql_error());
        $sellerqueryrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($sellersql);

            //Check to see if the listing is an Auction or Fixed Price
            if ($endauctionrow['auc_fp'] == "Auction") {

            //Global variables for Auction listings
            $bidmaxquery = "SELECT * FROM bids WHERE listing_id=$listingid ORDER BY bid DESC LIMIT 1";
            $bidmax = mysql_query($bidmaxquery) or die('SQL Error :: '.mysql_error());
            $bidmaxrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($bidmax);
            $highestbid = $bidmaxrow['bid'];
            $highestbidderid = $bidmaxrow['user_id'];

            $highestbidderquery = "SELECT * FROM settings WHERE user_id=$highestbidderid";
            $highestbidder = mysql_query($highestbidderquery) or die('SQL Error :: '.mysql_error());
            $highestbidderrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($highestbidder);
            $highestbiddername = $highestbidderrow['display_name'];

                //Check to see if the item quantity is zero (has it been sold yet?)
                if ($itemquantity < "1") {

                        //Set the message for an Auction that is marked as sold
                        $itemmessage = 'According to our records, your auction has sold.  The winning bidder was <a href="http://myauctionpage.com/mypage.php?user='.$highestbidderid.'">'.$highestbiddername.'</a>.  Please be sure to contact the winning bidder for payment and to work out deliver/shipping details. If you chose to include a PayPal Buy Now button for your listing, please check your PayPal account for shipping/delivery instructions as My Auction Page does not handle any shipping or payment processing.<br /><br />If for some reason an agreement cannot be reached with the buyer, you may opt to offer the item to the next highest bidder.  The bid history can be found on the listing page here <a href="http://myauctionpage.com/item.php?item='.$listingid.'">'.$endauctionrow['title'].'</a><br /><br />Thank You,<br />My Auction Page Administration';

                } else {
                    //Check to see if any bids were placed
                    if (mysql_num_rows($bidmax) == "1") {
                    //Set the message for an Auction that has at least one bid but has not yet been marked as sold.
                    $itemmessage = 'According to our records, your item has not yet been paid for.  The winning bidder was <a href="http://myauctionpage.com/mypage.php?user='.$highestbidderid.'">'.$highestbiddername.'</a>.  Please be sure to contact the winning bidder for payment and to work out deliver/shipping details. If you chose to include a PayPal Buy Now button for your listing, please check your PayPal account for shipping/delivery instructions as My Auction Page does not handle any shipping or payment processing.<br /><br />If for some reason the winning bidder cannot be contacted for payment or an agreement cannot be reached, you may opt to offer the item to the next highest bidder.  The bid history can be found on the listing page here <a href="http://myauctionpage.com/item.php?item='.$listingid.'">'.$endauctionrow['title'].'</a><br /><br />Thank You,<br />My Auction Page Administration';
                    } else {
                    //Set the message for an Auction that has no bids and has been marked as sold.
                    $itemmessage = 'According to our records there were no bids on your item.  You may reactivate your listing easily by following the link above and clicking "Edit Listing" to extend the Auction End Date.';
                        }
                }
                //Finish compiling the email variables
                $email = $sellerqueryrow['email'];
                $subject = "Your Auction listing has expired at MyAuctionPage.com!";
                $message = 'Hello '.$sellerqueryrow['display_name'].',<br /><br />Your listing for <a href="http://myauctionpage.com/item.php?item='.$listingid.'">'.$endauctionrow['title'].'</a> at My Auction Page has expired.   '.$itemmessage.'<br /><br />Thank You,<br />My Auction Page Administration';

                require_once 'classes/class.generalemail.php';
                if ($mailsendreport == "1") {
                    $updatecron = "UPDATE listings SET cron_ended=1 WHERE id=$listingid";
                    mysql_query($updatecron) or die('SQL Error :: '.mysql_error());
                    }

            } else {

            //Send the email for a Fixed Price listing
            if ($itemquant < "1") {
            $itemmessage = 'According to our records, your item has sold.  If you chose to include a PayPal Buy Now button for your listing, please check your PayPal account for shipping/delivery instructions as My Auction Page does not handle any shipping or payment processing.  If you have more of this item to sell, and since this was a Fixed Price listing, you may edit your listing and extend the date by following the link above and clicking "Edit Listing".  You may then update the number of items you have for sale.';
            } else {
            $itemmessage = 'According to our records, your item has not sold.  If you would like to relist your item you may edit your listing and extend the date by following the link above and clicking "Edit Listing".  If this item has sold, please follow the link above, log in, and click the button "Mark this item as sold" to let others know it is no longer available.';
            }
            $subject = "Your listing has expired at MyAuctionPage.com!";
            $message = 'Hello '.$sellerqueryrow['display_name'].',<br /><br />Your listing for <a href="http://myauctionpage.com/item.php?item='.$listingid.'">'.$endauctionrow['title'].'</a> at My Auction Page has expired.   '.$itemmessage.'<br /><br />Thank You,<br />My Auction Page Administration';

                require_once 'classes/class.generalemail.php';
                if ($mailsendreport == "sent") {
                    $updatecron = "UPDATE listings SET cron_ended=1 WHERE id=$listingid";
                    mysql_query($updatecron) or die('SQL Error :: '.mysql_error());
                    }
            }

        }

    } else {
    }
```

Can anyone help me figure out why this is only looping through 1 auction and why I'm getting the error.  `SQL Error :: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1`

After taking suggestions and numbering the die statements I have narrowed down the problem.  Here is the portion of code throwing the error:

```
//Global variables for Auction listings
            $bidmaxquery = "SELECT * FROM bids WHERE listing_id=$listingid ORDER BY bid DESC LIMIT 1";
            $bidmax = mysql_query($bidmaxquery) or die('SQL Error 3 :: '.mysql_error());
            $bidmaxrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($bidmax);
            $highestbid = $bidmaxrow['bid'];
            $highestbidderid = $bidmaxrow['user_id'];

            $highestbidderquery = "SELECT * FROM settings WHERE user_id=$highestbidderid";
            $highestbidder = mysql_query($highestbidderquery) or die('SQL Error 4 :: '.mysql_error());
            $highestbidderrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($highestbidder);
            $highestbiddername = $highestbidderrow['display_name'];
```

Comment: @echo_me MySQL line 1 refers to the first line of the query, which is usually the entire query.

Comment: You could start by numbering the `SQL Error ::` messages. Make them `SQL Error (1)`, 2, 3, etc. Then you know which one is broken.

Comment: Since the error message is kind of useless, modify your die() statements to give you a hint as to WHICh query is faling, e.g. `... or die('query #1: ' . mysql_error())`; This'll at least narrow it down to which of your queries is causing the problem. however, since you get a useless error message, the problem is probably an undefined/typoed variable name, so the END of the query string comes out blank, e.g. `SELECT .... WHERE field=`.

Comment: Thank you. I numbered the statements and modified the original question with the portion of code giving the error.

Comment: The portion of code contains two sql queries. Which one produces the error message?

Answer (score 0):

What is the error now? In which line it is now? Both the id's `listing_id` and `user_id` are 
integers? or strings?

if strings, then you should use :

```
$bidmaxquery = "SELECT * FROM bids WHERE listing_id="' .$listingid. '" ORDER BY bid DESC LIMIT 1";
            $bidmax = mysql_query($bidmaxquery) or die('SQL Error 3 :: '.mysql_error());
            $bidmaxrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($bidmax);
            $highestbid = $bidmaxrow['bid'];
            $highestbidderid = $bidmaxrow['user_id'];

            $highestbidderquery = "SELECT * FROM settings WHERE user_id="' .$highestbidderid. '"";
            $highestbidder = mysql_query($highestbidderquery) or die('SQL Error 4 :: '.mysql_error());
            $highestbidderrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($highestbidder);
            $highestbiddername = $highestbidderrow['display_name'];

//Sorry unable to post this as a comment. Reputation does not allow me!
```